# SwiftUI ScrollView can't scroll down to all the content of ZStack

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, zstack

SwiftUI ScrollView can't scroll all down to all the content of the included ZStack.

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var colors: [Color] = [.red, .orange, .yellow, .green, .mint, .teal, .cyan, .blue, .indigo, .purple, .pink, .brown ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                ForEach(0..<10) {i in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
                        .fill(colors[i])
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 300 )
                        .offset(x: 0, y: CGFloat(i) * 200)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is from using `ZStack` and `offset` together. `offset` doesn't adjust the frame of the view. If you set the background color of your `ZStack`, you will notice it doesn't contain all of the rectangles.

[image]

Also, the default alignment of a `ZStack` is `.center` which would not be what you want.

To fix your problem, there are many things you can do. For one, you can add a vertical padding to each view, in place of the offset. Also set the alignment of the `ZStack` the top:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView() {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                ForEach(0..<colors.count) { index in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                        .fill(colors[index])
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                        .padding(.top, CGFloat(index) * 100)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for point the two key points: offset doesn't change the size of ZStack; ZStack's default alignment is center. So it seems the only way to use ScrollView and ZStack with offset is to set the frame height of the ZStack like the following code show.

Answer (score 0):

Thank ColdLogic for pointing the two key points: offset doesn't change the size of ZStack; ZStack's default alignment is center. So it seems the only way to use ScrollView and ZStack with offset is to set the frame height to the actual height of its content of the ZStack.

Here is the code:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var colors: [Color] = [.red, .orange, .yellow, .green, .mint, .teal, .cyan, .blue, .indigo, .purple, .pink, .brown ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Color.black
                    ForEach(0..<colors.count) {i in
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
                            .fill(colors[i])
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 300 )
                            .offset(x: 0, y: CGFloat(i) * 200)
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: CGFloat(200*(colors.count-1))+300)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you did in your answer, not on a comment to a different answer, as the order may change anytime.